# fputcsv won't use tabs

Tags: php, fputcsv

Ok barring the possibility that I am going completely mad, has anyone else encountered an issue where fputcsv insists on using commas as a delimiter when it is explicitly told to use a tab. The following is my code which outputs the right fields but seperated by a comma rather than a tab!!!

```
 $headers = array(
                  'Name', 
                  'DOB', 
                  'Height', 
                  'Hair Colour', 
                  'Weight', 
                  'Eye Colour'
                 );
 $file_handle = fopen( $config['paths']['records'], 'w' );
 fputcsv( $file_handle, $headers, "\t" );
 fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.  What version of PHP are you using?  Are you sure that you are looking at the newly written file?

Comment: @TimCooper Tim please accept my apologies and thanks for your help. This turned out to be one of those stupid infuriating errors. The ftp client that I was using had somehow lost its connection to the file that I was editing locally. The client still showed as connected but any saves I made were not being propagated across to the server. It's one of those errors that makes you feel a right idiot but was so silent I had not noticed it.

Comment: Since this was just a mistake, then delete this post.